# How write query to pull data from some tables for view model lists?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, viewmodel, join

Generally I am looking for a solution to pull data from database to fill my view model list for many tables. I need your help for 2 tables for example.

Assume that I have `Category` and `Product` models and appropriate tables in database.

```
public class Category 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
}
```

I want to load view model list for `Product` from db. `ProductViewModel` is like:

```
public class ProductViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public int CategoryName { get; set; }
}
```

My sql query is

```
SELECT products.Id as Id, products.Name as Name, products.CategoryId as CategoryId, categories.Name as CategoryName 
FROM Products as products, Categories as categories WHERE products.CategoryId = categories.Id
```

But, there is a products that have not category, so, `CategoryId == 0`, (or for `string` types, value is `null` or `empty`).

In this case, my query does not load all products, because, some products has not category.

I want to load all products, and give `empty` or `null` values to `CategoryName` properties, which has not category. How should I change my query or how can I solve issues similar this?

Thanks in advanced

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Left Outer Join` will serve the purpose here. Re-write query as:

```
SELECT products.Id as Id,
       products.Name as Name,
       products.CategoryId as CategoryId,
       isnull(categories.Name,'') as CategoryName 
FROM Products as products
Left Outer Join Categories as categories On products.CategoryId = categories.Id
```

Actually comma between tables followed by matching condition in where clause is ANSI SQL-89 Syntax. It's equivalant ANSI SQL-92 Syntax is Inner Join. So you are gettig only matching rows becuase you have used such a join. Replacing that with Left Outer actually made the new matching condition as : Get *all* rows from Left table (Products) and matching rows from right table Categories and in case when no match is found then add CategoryName  as Null in those rows.